# How does Presto collect runtime memory?

Tags: presto

I'm learning Presto, I'm interested in Presto's runtime resource management.

I've learned that the ClusterMemoryManager checks memory periodically, but I'm confused about the collection of runtime memory.

```
for (QueryExecution query : queries) {
            long bytes = query.getUserMemoryReservation();
            DataSize sessionMaxQueryMemory = getQueryMaxMemory(query.getSession());
            long queryMemoryLimit = Math.min(maxQueryMemory.toBytes(), sessionMaxQueryMemory.toBytes());
            totalBytes += bytes;
            if (resourceOvercommit(query.getSession()) && outOfMemory) {
                // If a query has requested resource overcommit, only kill it if the cluster has run out of memory
                DataSize memory = succinctBytes(bytes);
                query.fail(new PrestoException(CLUSTER_OUT_OF_MEMORY,
                        format("The cluster is out of memory and %s=true, so this query was killed. It was using %s of memory", RESOURCE_OVERCOMMIT, memory)));
                queryKilled = true;
            }
            if (!resourceOvercommit(query.getSession()) && bytes > queryMemoryLimit) {
                DataSize maxMemory = succinctBytes(queryMemoryLimit);
                query.fail(exceededGlobalLimit(maxMemory));
                queryKilled = true;
            }
        }
```

How does Presto collection the running query's memory useage?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can view Query as a graph of task to do. Those tasks are distributed across nodes in the cluster and executed in multiple threads. The basic building block of such a task is an "Operator". Operators know their memory usage and report their it back through memory context classes. Reports coming from operators are aggregated on a node and also send back to the coordinator, which aggregates query total.

Comment: I've seen that in MemoryTrackingContext, 'This class is used to track memory usage at all levels (operator, driver, pipeline, etc.)'. Is '(operator, driver, pipeline, etc.)' hierarchical? The momory usage of driver come from the aggregation of it's operators's memory usage, and pipline's memory usage comes from drivers?

Comment: Exactly -- this is hierarchical just as you described it.